# What should I do to chat successfully?

Tags: support, chat

Due to local firewalls I need VPN to visit stackexchange networks. I've already added all sites with suffix "stackexchange.com" to my VPN list, but chatroom is still inaccessible for me. What kind of networks should I add to use the chatroom function? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a [list of domains which might be necessary when browsing or participating Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/81383/295232) on Meta Stack Exchange. Perhaps you're missing `ajax.googleapis.com` or `cdnjs.cloudflare.com`?

I have uBlock Origin installed, and AFAIK it tells you all domains which are being used for a page. For chat, it's the following list:

```
stackexchange.com
chat.stackexchange.com
ajax.googleapis.com
cloudflare.net
googleusercontent.com
gravatar.com
imgur.com
sstatic.net
```

Most notably, `cloudflare.net` is missing from the list on Meta.SE, so perhaps it's a little outdated.

Comment: It works. Much appreciation.

Comment: @User628759: You could be the most helpful to others who have a similar problem if you were specific about what changes you made to get chat rooms working for you, and, if possible, identify what was the key issue. Remember, you're not here just to get answers for yourself, you're here to participate in the sharing of knowledge.

Comment: I agree with JonathanZ. @User628759 if you can answer your own question eventually, then it would be of great help for the community.

Comment: I have found this post on [meta.se]: [Unable to load Stack Exchange Chat when on VPN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/333374). (It is a year old, so maybe it is no longer relevant for the OP.) I mentioned this question in a comment - still I wanted to mention it here too, in case you want to post the same advice there. (I guess that other users with the same problem are more likely to search on [meta.se].)

Answer (score 8):

My solution: As @Glorfindel suggested, I added all the following domains to the PAC list.

```
ajax.googleapis.com
cloudflare.net
googleusercontent.com
gravatar.com
imgur.com
sstatic.net
stackexchange.com
chat.stackexchange.com
```

After doing so I can visit chatrooms. Therefore a promising solution is to add **all domains** he mentioned to the list for VPN permission.